# How to force the Read-only mode?

Tags: neovim, file, open, mode

**Greetings**

Today I was learning the different methods for opening a file in Vim, and I recently learned the `view [filename]` or `[vim_launcher] -R [file_name]`, while both of these commands are great, they don't actually force the Read-only mode, because you can still exit that mode and enter `insert` mode, the only good thing about the Read-only mode is that you will get a nice-looking warning message when trying to edit the file.

When you actually open a file in Read-only, you want to avoid any type of mutation by accident, but the corresponding methods are not a good patch for this specific context.

**I have done some digging but found no answer to this:**

> How to force the Read-only mode in the Vim | NVim text editor?

Comment: This question is essentially a special case of "how can I protect me from myself?" and the answer is a crushing "you cannot". Just don't change that file!

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a solution for this, you can use
the `-m` option in addition to the `-R` option, where m
stands for *no modification*, which stops you from
writing to the file, even if you have committed any
type of editing.

So `[vi_launcher] -R [file_name]` becomes
`[vi_launcher] -mR [file_name]`

I think this still can't replace the fork of the Read-only mode, there should be a better solution to this.

Comment: See `:help 'modifiable'` and `:help 'readonly'`

Answer (score 0):

I've aliased the `less.sh` script that ships with vim to `vless`. It does what you're asking for.

```bash
alias vless='/usr/local/share/vim/vim91/macros/less.sh'
```